# How to get only 1 image from a video javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This code creates several images of a video, however I would like it to generate only one image, I know it is in looping, but if I remove it from the looping it generates a single image infinitely
I need to get only one image, just a single one, when I tried to do this it repeat itself infinitely until the browser tab crashes
As you can see when running the snippet it generates several images, I need to generate only one of a specific time.

```js
var i = 0;
var video = document.createElement("video");
var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbs");

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
 thumbs.innerHTML = "";
    video.currentTime = i;
}, false);

video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {

    generateThumbnail(i);

    i++;

    if (i <= video.duration) {
        video.currentTime = i;
    }
 else {
  alert("done!")
    }

}, false);

video.preload = "auto";
video.src = "http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=6ffdd7d2229f9172";

function generateThumbnail() {
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = 160;
  c.height = 90;
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 160, 90);
  thumbs.appendChild(c);
}
```

```css
#video {width:320px}
```

```html
<div id=thumbs>Loading video in background...</div>
```

Comment: but if you're able to get a lot of images already, what is the problem you face while getting a single one? Looks like you're pretty much there already.

Comment: my goal is to get only one image, just a single one, when I tried to do this it repeat itself infinitely until the browser tab crashes, as you can see when running the snippet it generates several images, I need to generate only one of a specific time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
i++;

if (i <= video.duration) {
    video.currentTime = i;
}
else {
    alert("done!")
}
```

And replace `var i` with another var like `var time` then you will get the frame of a specific second, like `var time = 6`

```js
var time = 6;
var video = document.createElement("video");
var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbs");

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
 thumbs.innerHTML = "";
    video.currentTime = time;
}, false);

video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
    generateThumbnail(time); 
}, false);

video.preload = "auto";
video.src = "http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=6ffdd7d2229f9172";

function generateThumbnail() {
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = 160;
  c.height = 90;
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 160, 90);
  thumbs.appendChild(c);
}
```

```css
#video {width:320px}
```

```html
<div id=thumbs>Loading video in background...</div>
```